# Not able to display string from a resource in android

Tags: android, textview

### I am trying to display a string from a resource

I have displayed the resource of the string in the values folder

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
        android:paddingRight="4dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="140dp"
            android:background="@drawable/frame_background_for_rounded_corners_white_bkg" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/image_view_background_white_background" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="116dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/button_round_cornered_white_background"
                android:text="Button" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="141dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/BuffetOfferings-Breakfast-statement"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

---

In the values folder

---

**styles.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light" />

    <color name="TextColorForTextAboveImage">#FFFFFF</color>


    <string name="BuffetOfferings-Breakfast-statement">Tap the "Breakfast" to offer, then the days and time of its offerings to your customers</string>


</resources>
```

**My OUTPUT** ::

[image]

**Clearly you can see instead of text to display .... reference itself is displaying**

*How to resolve this !*

Comment: Try with removing desh(-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string names need to use `_` instead of `-`.

```
<string name="BuffetOfferings_Breakfast_statement"></string>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove your Dash(-) from `name` attribute.

```
 <string name="BuffetOfferingsBreakfaststatement">Tap the "Breakfast" to offer, then the days and time of its offerings to your customers</string>
```

For more information read [Document](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html).

Answer (score 0):

Replace the resource attribute as

```
 <string name="BuffetOfferings_Breakfast_statement">Tap the "Breakfast" to offer, then the days and time of its offerings to your customers</string>
```

replace hyphen '-' with underscore'_'

Answer (score 0):

You can't define **string** in `styles.xml` directly instead of you can **reference** to a String from `strings.xml`.

You should define your string in **strings.xml** and remove '-' use '_'

```
strings.xml
```

Use like this

```
<string name="BuffetOfferings_Breakfast_statement">Tap the "Breakfast" to offer, then the days and time of its offerings to your customers</string>
```

Hope this help you.